# how to pass object type as a parameter in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

below abstarct type created

```
create or replace TYPE    callbck      as table of callback_t;
```

abstract table

```
create or replace TYPE      CALLBACK_T                                          as object
  (
   url           varchar2(50),
   uri_key            number,
  );
```

below is the procedure used,

```
 procedure get_callback_info
  (
     pi_clbk               callbck      := callbck      (),
    requestor varchar2,
msg varchar2)
```

how to pass the parameter for the abstract object type to the procedure get_callback_info.

i have the abstract values 'http://test.com', and 1345 as the url and uri_key

Answer (score 1):

Say you have these types and procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CALLBACK_T AS OBJECT
(
    url VARCHAR2(50),
    uri_key NUMBER
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE callbck AS TABLE OF callback_t;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_callback_info(
                                              pi_clbk      IN     callbck := callbck(),
                                              requestor    IN     VARCHAR2,
                                              msg             OUT VARCHAR2
                                             ) IS
BEGIN
    /* whatever your code is */
    msg    := requestor || ' asked information on callbck with ' || pi_clbk.COUNT || ' elements';
END;
```

You can test your procedure with something like:

```
declare
   vCallbck   callbck;
   vRequestor varchar2(20) := 'a requestor';
   vMsg       varchar2(100);
begin
    /* populate the vCallbck with 10 records */
    select CALLBACK_T ('url ' || level, level)
    bulk collect into vCallbck
    from dual
    connect by level <= 10; 
    --
    get_callback_info(vCallbck, vRequestor, vMsg);
    --
    dbms_output.put_line(vMsg);
end;
/
```

If you want to test with a single value, you can use:

```
declare
   vCallbck   callbck;
   vRequestor varchar2(20);
   vMsg       varchar2(100);
begin
    vCallbck := callbck();
    vCallbck.extend(1);
    vCallbck(1) := CALLBACK_T('http://test.com', '1345');
    --
    get_callback_info(vCallbck, vRequestor, vMsg);
    --
    dbms_output.put_line(vMsg);
end;
/
```