# How to pass object of object type as a parameter in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracle-objects

This is the next level question for [how to pass object type as a parameter in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263056/how-to-pass-object-type-as-a-parameter-in-oracle).

My question is in the same context a bit deeper with master-child nested level relationship, which is object with in the object.
And I didn't find any way to call such procedure from PL-SQL.

Let's modify the example given in the above question as below :

---

Creating objects and types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE domain_details_ot AS OBJECT
(
    domain_name VARCHAR2(50),
    domain_ip   VARCHAR2(50)

);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE domain_details_nt AS TABLE OF domain_details_ot;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CALLBACK_T AS OBJECT
(
    url VARCHAR2(50),
    uri_key NUMBER,
    domains  domain_details_nt

);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE callbck AS TABLE OF callback_t;
```

---

Create and Insert Statements for the requirement :

```
CREATE TABLE url_hdr
(url_hdr_id   INT 
, url VARCHAR2(100)
, url_key NUMBER
, CONSTRAINT url_hdr_pk PRIMARY KEY (url_hdr_id)
);

CREATE TABLE url_dtl
(url_dtl_id INT
, url_hdr_id   INT 
, domain_name VARCHAR2(500)
, domain_ip  VARCHAR2(50)
, CONSTRAINT url_dtl_pk PRIMARY KEY (url_dtl_id)
, CONSTRAINT url_dtl_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (url_hdr_id)  REFERENCES url_hdr(url_hdr_id)
);

INSERT INTO url_hdr VALUES (1, 'www.abc.com', 12345);
INSERT INTO url_hdr VALUES (2, 'www.xyz.com',23456);

INSERT INTO url_dtl VALUES (1, 1, 'abc.com', '0.0.0.0');
INSERT INTO url_dtl VALUES (2, 1, 'def.com', '0.0.0.1');
INSERT INTO url_dtl VALUES (3, 2, 'uvw.com', '0.0.0.2');
INSERT INTO url_dtl VALUES (4, 2, 'xyz.com', '0.0.0.3');
COMMIT;

SELECT uh.url, uh.url_key, ud.domain_name, ud.domain_ip
FROM url_hdr uh
,url_dtl ud
WHERE uh.url_hdr_id = ud.url_hdr_id
AND uh.url_hdr_id IN (1,2);
```

---

Procedure Sample Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_callback_info(
                                              pi_clbk      IN     callbck := callbck()
                                             )
IS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..pi_clbk.COUNT
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('i : '||i ||' '||pi_clbk(i).url);
        FOR j IN 1..pi_clbk(i).domains.COUNT
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line('i : '||i || ' j : '||j ||' '||pi_clbk(i).uri_key);
            dbms_output.put_line('i : '||i || ' j : '||j ||' '||pi_clbk(i).domains(j).domain_name);
            dbms_output.put_line('i : '||i || ' j : '||j ||' '||pi_clbk(i).domains(j).domain_ip);
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

Since this is being called from Java code and there they can create object with in object. I don't need to call this from PL-SQL side and I am saved.

Now, my question is how to call such procedure from PL-SQL? I want to call this procedure for the records returned by the Select Statement. Basically I need to store these values in the variable of type callbck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiate an object instance the same way you would do it in SQL, e.g:

```
select callbck
       ( callback_t
         ( 'www.abc.com'
         , 12345
         , domain_details_nt
           ( domain_details_ot('abc.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.0')
           , domain_details_ot('xyz.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.1') ) )
       , callback_t
         ( 'www.xyz.com'
         , 23456
         , domain_details_nt
           ( domain_details_ot('xyz.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.2')
           , domain_details_ot('abc.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.3') ) )
       )
from   dual;
```

So, to call a procedure it would be something like

```
begin
    get_callback_info(
        callbck
        ( callback_t
          ( 'www.abc.com'
          , 12345
          , domain_details_nt
            ( domain_details_ot('abc.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.0')
            , domain_details_ot('xyz.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.1') ) )
        , callback_t
          ( 'www.xyz.com'
          , 23456
          , domain_details_nt
            ( domain_details_ot('xyz.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.2')
            , domain_details_ot('abc.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.3') ) )
        )
    );
end;
```

Comment: Thank You So much. Its working as expected. I have one more thing in my mind, here the values which are being passed are hardcoded. Now, How to call this procedure if I need to pick the values from a table, store them in a variable of type callbck and then use that variable in the function. If its not a nested one, I can use bulk collect as given in the reference question's answer. Can we do it like this way here as well?

Comment: Sure, you can have a PL/SQL variable of type `callbck` and pass that to the procedure.

Comment: Will, you please tell me, how shall I do this. I've edited the original question to have the insert statements for the table. Here I need to call this procedure for these records where url_hdr_id IN (1,2).
DECLARE 
lv_callbck callbck;
BEGIN
select callbck
       ( callback_t
         ( 'www.abc.com'
         , 12345
         , domain_details_nt
           ( domain_details_ot('abc.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.0')
           , domain_details_ot('xyz.com', domain_ip => '0.0.0.1') ) )
 )
       INTO lv_callbck
from   dual;
END;

Can we have it from the select stmt using the table?